# Why do two population estimates a and b show correlation, but the features composing estimate a have no/unclear effects on estimate b?

Tags: regression, psychology

I got two population estimates a and b calculated each by a random forest regression. Variable c is then subtracted from a and b. As expected, the estimates a-c and b-c show a nice correlation (r = .80).

Calculation A: Then, for all features used for the estimation of a, I performed sperate linear regression for each feature as independent variable and always b-c as dependent variable. However, the effects of each feature on estimate b-c are significant, but are in the opposite direction. E.g. feature z is expected to have a positive effect on estimate b-c, but the resulting effect is negative.

Calculation B: In order to solve this issue and also in line with previous research, I tried the following: I performed the same seperate linear regressions between the features composing estimate a and estimate b-c as independent variable, but now with variable c, the same as mentioned above, as covariate. The resulting effects of the respective features shrinked substantially, were not signficant anymore and were still partially in the opposite direction.

My Question: How can it be explained that the population estimates -c correlate with eachother, but the features, which compose estimate a, don´t show any effects (Calculation B) or opposite effects (Calculation A) on estimate b-c? And is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!